# How to pass language from web page to Keycloak using Spring security adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

I work on a web app secured by Keycloak, and I have a small problem regarding language of the keycloak login page.

My web app starts with a home page on which there is two buttons.
The first button allow to enter some parts of the app that are not secured.
The second button allow to enter the whole app, secured by Keycloak (using Spring security adapter).
On the home page, I have the possibility to change the language of the web app.
If I change the language on the home page, the not secured part of the web app will be in the chosen language.
But if I change the language on the home page, when I click on the button to access to the secured part of the app, I am redirected to the Keycloak login page, but the language on the Keycloak login page doesn't change, it stays as the default one and I have to change it manually.

I have seen that kc_locale can be used in the url of Keycloak to set the language that Keycloak must use.
The problem is that I am not calling Keycloak, Spring security adapter is, and I have no idea how to pass the information to the adapter.
I tried a few things, but nothing worked.
Is there a way to do that and if yes, how ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the best I could do is  to provide a login link with  the locale as a parameter like this

/sso/login?ui_locales=en-US

/sso/login is configured by the Keycloak Spring Adapter - not by me - so it should work for you too.

The class [OAuthRequestAuthenticator](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java) which does the whole redirect stuff picks the parameter up and passes it on to keycloak.
Look for OAuth2Constants.UI_LOCALES_PARAM in code

However this doesn't work if you go first to a protected url and the adapter redirects internally to /sso/login (without the locale param).

Cheers,

Ana